# Failed to start gitlab-runner: The specified service does not exist as an installed service

Tags: gitlab

Throw err while I have start GitLab-runner.
`error:"The specified service does not exist as an installed service."`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCxPs.jpg)

If anybody knows please help me.

Answer (score 3):

GO to cmd --> right click as "administrator" type and go to the path where gitlab-runner.exe available and then -->gitlab-runner.exe install